# Cambiar tipo de dato

Tags: python, databricks

```
   df = jugadores.where(     (col("position") == "Forward")
                 &      (col("played_time") >=2500)
                )
   df2 = df.select(
      df.player_name.alias("jugador"),
      F.col("shots_total").cast("float"),
      F.col("goals").cast("float")
      )
   df2 = df2.withColumn("% Efectividad", df["shots_total" / "goals"])
   df2.select("player_name", "shots_total", "goals").display()
```

Buenos dias,
Comprendo el tipo de error que me da pero ya he cambiado el tipo de dato de string a float, no entiendo porque persiste. El error me lo da en la linea 9 (df2 = df2.withColumn....

Error:

> TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) 
> in  7 F.col("goals").cast("float") 8 ) ----> 9 df2 =
> df2.withColumn("% Efectividad", df["shots_total" / "goals"]) 10
> df2.select("player_name", "shots_total", "goals").display() TypeError:
> unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Gracias y saludos*

Comment: Creo que deberias añadir exactamente cual es el error.

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2546904138499777> in <module>
      7           F.col("goals").cast("float")
      8           )
----> 9 df2 = df2.withColumn("% Efectividad", df["shots_total" / "goals"])
     10 df2.select("player_name", "shots_total", "goals").display()

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: El problema es aqui: `df["shots_total" / "goals"]`. No puedes aplicar divisiones a cadenas. Quizas la solución es  `df["shots_total"] / df["goals"] ` pero solo puedo conjeturar porque no se lo que es  `df `

Comment: Gracias David, 
Te pongo en situación, df es la variable de una tabla con diferentes valores para jugadores (nombre, posicion, goles, tiros, etc..) estoy tratando de añadir una columna nueva que me de el porcentaje de acierto entre dos columnas ya existentes. Por lo que veo el error es que no puedo porque el tipo de dato.

Comment: No, el error es que a `df` le intentas pasar algo entre corchetes: `df[algo]`, por lo que python antes debe evaular ese `algo` que en este caso es `"short_total" / "goals"`, es decir, una división de dos cadenas, lo que no tiene sentido. Supongo que lo que quieres es dividir la columna "short_total" entre la columna "goals", lo cual sería más bien `df["short_total"] / df["goals"]`, como te ha dicho @DavidMiró